# Is there a way to clear/remove a specific resources from browser cache rather than clearing entire cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, web-applications, browser

For instance in Chrome, I'm working on a webapp (which is heavy, takes ~5 seconds) has lot of static resources (JS) files and CSS to load in the first time. To reflect changes of one JS, I need to reload the webpage with "Empty Clear Cache".

If there can be a way to only remove specific resource(s) JS files from cache (so to force refetch from server), my testing time can be reduced by great extent.

Comment: yes there is  chrome extension called "Clear Cache". Why not develop on localhost?

Comment: Copy the URL to the browser of the file you want to clear the cache for. Put it into a new tab. Hard Refresh [Ctrl/Shift - F5], switch back to the tab and refresh.

Comment: @Kyslik I am working on an integration server which if I setup on local will be very slow. So localhost is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

A technique is to add a random parameter to the url of assets you don't want cached.
Depending on what your server-side language is, you might be able to do something like the following:

```
<script src="my.js?_=<%= encode(new Date().toString()) %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PHP backend, you could tack on a random number to the JS file URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js?<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

This will cause the browser to re-fetch it every time from server as the URL will differ.

Comment: I am using ExtJS to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Specific resources can be reloaded individually if you change the date and time on your files on the server. **"Clearing cache"** is not as easy as it should be. Instead of clearing cache on my browsers, I realized that "touching" the server files cached will actually change the date and time of the source file cached on the server (Tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and most browsers will automatically download the most current fresh copy of whats on your server (code, graphics any multimedia too). I suggest you just copy the most current scripts on the server and **"do the touch thing"** solution before your program runs, so it will change the date of all your problem files to a most current date and time, then it downloads a fresh copy to your browser:

```
<?php
touch('/www/sample/file1.css');
touch('/www/sample/file2.css');
touch('/www/sample/file2.css') ?>
```

then ... the rest of your program...

It took me some time to resolve this issue (as many browsers act differently to different commands, but they all check time of files and compare to your downloaded copy in your browser, if different date and time, will do the refresh), If you can't go the supposed right way, there is always another usable and better solution to it. Best Regards and happy camping. By the way touch(); or alternatives work in many programming languages inclusive in javascript bash sh php and you can include or call them in html.